# Cannot expand guest screen size

Tags: virtualbox, redhat-enterprise-linux

I apologize if this is a redundant question, but I have tried various suggested solution to increase the guest screen size with no luck. Guest Additions compiled and installed without any error, and other guest addtions functions such as mouse, clipboard work just fine.  Here is my environment:

```
    Windows 10 /x64 host
 RHEL guest.

        Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 4 20:48:51 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
        [root@localhost leor]# cat /etc/*-release
        NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
        VERSION="7.6 (Maipo)"
        ID="rhel"
        ID_LIKE="fedora"
        VARIANT="Server"
        VARIANT_ID="server"
        VERSION_ID="7.6"
        PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
        ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
        CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.6:GA:server"
        HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
        BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

        REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
        REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.6
        REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
        REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.6"
        Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)
        Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)


        VBox Version 5.2.22 r126460 (Qt5.6.2)
        vbox guest 5.2.22
```

I have the vbox session log file, but did not include it here, as it is huge.  Can share if anyone is interested.

THanks

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem often, especially after Windows updates.

I use this work-around:
Inside the guest, press Host-C twice, and then choose View/Fullscreen. (Host is Right-CTRL, if you didn't change it).
That typically switches successfully to full screen resolution; after that you can now change the resolution as you like.

Note that after major windows updates, it typically needs *another* reboot to be able to handle that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it did not help. :(